# JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE variable global_var is undeclared

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I have a global variable storing a array passed from server.

> HTML file

```
global_var = {{hello_obj}}
```

> hello.js

var hello = global_var;
Closure compiler gives error:

> [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable global_var is undeclared

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.global_var` will tell Closure this is a global.

If you use (or intend to use) advanced optimizations, you may wish to go with `window['global_var']` to ensure the property isn't renamed.

Comment: Closure compiler will complain window.global_var not defined in hello.js. Not work. Do I need to define it in external.js, which is another file, and include external.js with hello.js in BUILD file?